# Frobenius Norm to L2 norm Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Here is the problem: if $v^1$, $v^2$, ..., $v^d$ is an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{R}^d$, then show that 
$$
||A - A\sum_{i = 1}^k v^i(v^i)^T ||^2_F = \sum_{i = k+1}^d||Av^i ||_2^2.
$$

I am having trouble understanding this step of a longer proof.  The text that I got this from just says that this holds because $v^1$, $v^2$, ..., $v^d$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Answer (score 1):

since both norms are invariant under an orthogonal change of coordinates, we may take the $v_i$ to be the standard basis. if we write $e_j$ for the row vector $(e^j)^T$, then the matrix $A'(k)$ defined by:
$$
A'(k)=A' - \sum_{j=1}^k A'e^j e_j
$$
is simply $A'$ with its first $k$ columns set to zero.

for a real, square matrix, the square of the Frobenius norm is the sum of the squared $L_2$ magnitudes of its columns. so in the statement you wish to demonstrate, the $LHS$ is the sum of the squared $L_2$ norms of its columns indexed from $k+1$ to $d$.

on the RHS, the sum $\sum_{j=k+1}^d ||A'e^j||^2$ is the same thing, expressed directly.

Answer (score 1):

Since $v^i$ is an orthonormal basis, the matrix $V:=[v^1,\ldots,v^d]$ is orthogonal, that is,
$$
VV^T=\sum_{i=1}^d v^i(v^i)^T=I,
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. So,
$$
A=AVV^T=A\sum_{i=1}^d v^i(v^i)^T=A\sum_{i=1}^k v^i(v^i)^T+\sum_{i=k+1}^d Av^i(v^i)^T,
$$
which gives
$$
A-A\sum_{i=1}^k v^i(v^i)^T=\sum_{i=k+1}^d Av^i(v^i)^T.
$$
It remains to find the expression for the Frobenius norm of the right-hand side. Set $W:=[v^{k+1},\ldots,v^d]$. Since $v^{k+1},\ldots,v^d$ are orthonormal, $W^TW=I$. Then using $\|X\|_F^2=\mathrm{trace}(XX^T)$, we get
$$
\begin{split}
\left\|\sum_{i=k+1}^d Av^i(v^i)^T\right\|_F^2&=\|AWW^T\|_F^2=\mathrm{trace}[(AWW^T)(AWW^T)^T]\\&=\mathrm{trace}(AWW^TWW^TA^T)=\mathrm{trace}(AWW^TA^T)\\&=\mathrm{trace}[(AW)(AW)^T]=\|AW\|_F^2\\&=\sum_{i=k+1}^d\|Av^i\|_2^2.
\end{split}
$$